# Use expression in table as select statement without result

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-insert, dynamic-sql

In relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078119/how-to-use-column-value-as-select-expression) I'm using the following code to execute select queries saved in a table.

```
begin
  for rec in (select col1,col2,col3 from Table_1) loop
    execute immediate 'insert into Table_3 SELECT DISTINCT ''' || rec.col1 ||''', CODE, '''|| rec.col2 ||''' FROM Table_2 WHERE col1 = ''' || rec.col1 || ''' AND  ' || rec.col2;
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

It is possible that the select distinct statement, returns no values from Table_2. In the current code, no lines will be inserted into Table_3 when there are no values returned from Table_2.

My Goal is to, in the case no lines are returned from Table_2, Null values are inserted in Table_3. Like the following example because rec.col1 holds a value.

```
+----------+-------+-------+
| 3col1    | 3col2 | 3col3 |
+----------+-------+-------+
| rec.col1 | Null  | Null  |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function:

```
insert into Table_3
    with t as (
          SELECT DISTINCT . . .
          FROM Table_2
          WHERE col1 . . .
         )
    select t.*
    from t
    union all
    select ?, NULL, NULL, . . .
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from t);
```

You need to fill in the `. . .` with your values.  You might want to learn to use parameters with `execute immediate`.